# Loading Fortran function from dynamic library: Debug vs Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, fortran, intel-fortran

I wrote some code to load a dynamic library that was compiled in Fortran. Among the exported functions in the Fortran library are exported setters and getters. I'm attempting to load these setters and getters using the Windows API. While this works for my code built in debug. It does not work with my code built in release. In release, when I attempt to pass `1.0f` through to `set()` I'm seeing `0.0f` in the debugger when I step into the fortran code.

Edit: Another observation I forgot to mention. If I only load the `setValue()` function. My problem completely goes away. Only when I load additional functions from the library do I start having the issues I'm seeing.

**Compilers**

- Intel Fortran 2017 Update 5
- Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.2

**Debugging**

I've determined that when my C++ code is compiled in release, my loaded `set()` function will pass `0.0f` to the fortran function. This was discovered by loading the debug version of the fortran library and running it through Visual Studio's debugger. Performing the same thing with the debug build of my code yields the correct value getting passed through to the fortran function.

I've tried the following in the attempt to figure out what is happening:

- Tried loading both Debug and Release binaries of the compiled Fortran in both Debug and Release builds of my loader. Only works for my Debug build of the loader.
- Rebuilt the Fortran code verifying compiler flags such as Mutithreaded Debug DLL for Debug and Multithreaded DLL for Release.
- Performed a dumpbin of the fortran binary to verify function address are getting correctly loaded; they are.

**FORTRAN**

```
    REAL FUNCTION getValue()
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, c:: getValue
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INCLUDE 'VALUE.CMN'

    getValue = VAL
    RETURN
      END FUNCTION getValue

    SUBROUTINE setValue(x)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, c:: setValue
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    INCLUDE 'VALUE.CMN'

    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: x

    VAL = x 

      END SUBROUTINE setValue
```

**C++**

```
const auto handle = reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(LoadLibrary("fortran_value.dll"));

typedef void(*Set)(float&);
typedef float(*Get)(void);

const auto set = reinterpret_cast<Set>(GetProcAddress(handle, "setvalue"));
const auto get = reinterpret_cast<Get>(GetProcAddress(handle, "getvalue"));

auto value = 1.0f;

// 0.0f gets set to the internal fotran variable when this code is compile in release.
set(value);

// Only succeeds when this code is compiled in Debug.
// get() returns 0.0f when this code is compiled in Release.
if(value == get()) 
{
    std::cout << "Success!\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Fail!\n";
}

FreeLibrary(handle);
```

I'm at a loss. Any thoughts or suggestions on what could be happening here?

**COMPLETE COMPILEABLE EXAMPLE**

The following are links to a complete compilable example of the problem I'm having. After having more time to spend with it. It appears my issues stems from my attempts at making a wrapper with the above code.

[fortran_value.dll](https://gist.github.com/ASxa86/0b630a0dad62f91bb8df6e7759c8c3ce)

[fortran_value_test.exe](https://gist.github.com/ASxa86/e777d2b4856210ffd28391429267105f)

Comment: What does *"not work"*? What happens exactly? Any error messages or something?

Comment: I updated my C++ code with some comments that explains the values I'm seeing from the debugger. In release, I pass 1.0f through `set()` but when stepping through the fortran code I'm seeing 0.0f. In debug, it's working as intended I pass 1.0f in and I see 1.0f in the debugger.

Comment: Be very, *very* suspicious of what you see when you examine variables in the debugger.  I would strongly recommend stepping through the assembler instructions, and looking at the what it is doing.

Comment: Is this 32 bit or 64 bit?  I think you have got a mismatch in the calling conventions, or you are confused by what your debugger is showing you.

Comment: This is 64 bit only. I only have the 64 bit fortran compiler installed on my machine.

Comment: You need to declare the functions as __stdcall.  By default, C++ functions are __cdecl which stacks and unstacks the parameters differently.

Comment: When I tried your syntax for declaration of `handle` I got `sizeof(handle)=4`, which is a fail in 64-bit code. I don't know how declarations work in C++, but `const HANDLE handle = 0;` got handle to at least be the right size (8), assuming `#include <windows.h>`.

Comment: In the set function, the parameter should be a pointer to an int: not a reference.  References in Fortran are different from those in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the responses to my question I spent more time debugging the fortran code and doing some more research. As discussed in the responses to my question, there was a mismatch in calling conventions. By using bind(c) in my fortran code, my problem was resolved.

> Since Fortran 2003 (ISO/IEC 1539-1:2004(E)) there is a standardized way to generate procedure and derived-type declarations and global variables which are interoperable with C (ISO/IEC 9899:1999). The **bind(C)** attribute has been added to inform the compiler that a symbol shall be interoperable with C; also, some constraints are added. Note, however, that not all C features have a Fortran equivalent or vice versa. For instance, neither C’s unsigned integers nor C’s functions with variable number of arguments have an equivalent in Fortran

```
    REAL FUNCTION getValue() bind(c)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: getValue
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INCLUDE 'VALUE.CMN'

    getValue = VAL
    RETURN
      END FUNCTION getValue

    SUBROUTINE setValue(x) bind(c)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: setValue
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    INCLUDE 'VALUE.CMN'

    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: x

    VAL = x 

      END SUBROUTINE setValue
```